# What is the use of Comparator.comparing in respect to Comparator

Tags: java, lambda, collections, comparator

As far as I understand Comparator is a functional interface used to compare 2 objects with `int compare(T o1, T o2)` as the abstract function that takes two argument.
but there is also a function `Comparator.comparing(s->s)` that can take a lambda function with only one input parameter.
for Example to sort a Collection using streams

```
        List<String> projects=Arrays.asList("abc","def","sss","aaa","bbb");
        projects.stream().sorted((x,y)->y.compareTo(x)).forEach(s->System.out.println(s));
        projects.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(s->s)).forEach(s->System.out.println(s));
```

the sorted method takes a Comparator as a argument. So I am able to understand the first lambda expression but I wonder the use of `Comparator.comparing(s->s)` i.e. is `Comparator.comparing()` used for converting a single argument lambda expression to a double argument one or does it has some other use as well.
Also please explain the part of the below function declaration.

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
            Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

Comment: That is useful if your objects don't have a natural order or when you want a custom ordering. Example:  Imagine you have a list of persons `List<Person>  persons` which you want to sort by first name, age or .... It is handy and readable to have `...sorted(Comparator.comparing(p->p.getFirstName()))...` or as a method reference `...sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName))...` or `...sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge))...` instead of `.sorted((x,y)->y.getFirstName().compareTo(x.getFirstName()))` and so on

Comment: `Comparator.comparing` is much more difficult to mess up than manually implementing a `Comparator` otherwise.

Comment: Of course, it’s difficult to see the advantage when comparing two examples which are both useless, i.e. reinventing `Comparator.naturalOrder()`. In this case, you’d normally just use `.sorted()`, without specifying a comparator at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is `Comparator.comparing()` used for converting a single argument lambda expression to a double argument?

Yes, you can sort of think of it like that.

When sorting things, you are supposed to specify "given two things `a` and `b`, which of them is greater, or are they equal?" using a `Comparator<T>`. The `a` and `b` is why it has 2 lambda parameters, and you return an integer indicating your answer to that question.

However, a much more convenient way to do this is to specify "given a thing `x`, what part of `x` do you want to sort *by*?". And that is what you can do with the `keyExtractor` argument of `Comparator.comparing`.

Compare:

```
/*
given two people, a and b, the comparison result between a and b is the 
comparison result between a's name and b's name
*/
Comparator<Person> personNameComparator = 
    (a, b) -> a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());

/*
given a person x, compare their name
*/
Comparator<Person> personNameComparator = 
    Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getName()); // or Person::getName
```

The latter is clearly much more concise and intuitive. We tend to think about *what* things to sort by, rather than how exactly to compare two things, and the exact number to return depending on the comparison result.

As for the declaration for `comparing`:

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
            Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

The `<T, U extends Comparable<? super U>>` part first declares two generic type parameters - `T` is what the comparator compares (`Person` in the above case), and `U` is the type that you are actually comparing (`String` in the above case), hence it `extends Comparable`.

`keyExtractor` is the parameter you pass in, such as `x -> x.getName()`, that should answer the question of "when given a `T`, what is a `U` that you want to compare by?".

If you are confused by the `? super` and `? extends`, read [What is PECS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

If you haven't realised already, the implementation of `comparing` basically boils down to:

```
return (a, b) -> keyExtractor.apply(a).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(b));
```

Answer (score 6):

`Comparator#compare(T o1, T o2)` Compare two objects and returns an integer value based on this criteria:

- A negative value if o1 < o2
- A positive value if o1 > o2
- Zero if they are equal.

`Comparator.comparing(Function<? super T, ? extends U> key)` returns a `Comparator<T>` that compares by that sort key.

The main difference is that `compare` method provides a single point of comparison, whereas `comparing` chained to other functions to provide multiple points of comparison.

Suppose you have a class `Person`

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    // rest of class omitted
}
```

if you compare two `Person` instances `p1` vs `p2` using `compare(p1, p2)`, the comparison will be executed and the two objects will be sorted based on some natural ordering prescribed by the class. In contrast, if you want to compare the same two instances using `comparing()`, the comparison will be executed based on whichever criteria you choose to compare based on some attribute of the class. For example: `Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName)`.

Because `comparing` returns a `Comparator` rather than a value, as I stated before, you can chain multiple comparisons. For instance: `Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName).thenComparing(Person::getFirstName);`

As for the meaning of the return type `<T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T>`, you can find the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65468566/2851311).

I want to add that, classes must be comparable in order for `compare(T o1, T o2)` to work. String objects are comparable because they implement this interface. That said, if a class is not `Comparable`, you can still use `comparing` method because as I stated, you get to choose which attribute of the class you would like to use for the comparison and those attributes are likely to be comparable (i.e. String in the case of person's name or age in the above example).

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you have your custom object:

```
public class Person {

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  //getters and setters
}
```

Let's now say you have to compare people by their first names. One option is to write comparator like this:

```
Comparator<Person> comparator2 = (p1, p2) -> p1.getFirstName().compareTo(p2.getFirstName());
```

This should be obvious - get first name of one person, and compare it to the first name of other person. Other option is to write this same comparator using [Comparator.comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-). It will look like this:

```
Comparator<Person> comparator1 = Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getFirstName());
```

Or even better with method reference:

```
Comparator<Person> comparator1 = Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName);
```

The single argument you provide here is a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), it accepts a single parameter, this is why your lambda also uses a single parameter. The function here works as a key extractor - it extracts from your object the keys to be compared. It's like saying, get first name from first object and compare it to first name of second object.

Just note, that keys extracted like this **must** be [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). In the example above extracted key is `String`, which implements comparable.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

A `keyExtrator` is provided to compare the `object` or any `field` of the object as long as the `field` also implements `Comparable`.  What is returned is a `Comparator` that uses the `fields` `compareTo` method.

**The rest of the story**

Here is the complete method from the `Comparator` interface

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
            Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
        return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
            (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
    }
```

First, `Comparable` allows an object to provide a natural ordering by implementing the `Comparable interface` method of `int compareTo(ob)`.  So an object can compare itself to another instance of its own class (or perhaps ancestral class).

`Comparator` is a way to allow comparisons of related objects that don't implement the `Comparable interface`.  It is called by `compare(ob1, ob2)`.

The interface shown above allows a `Comparator` to be returned that makes use of the Object under comparison's `Comparable` implementation.  But it also allows for a part of that object (e.g. a field) to be obtained via a `keyExtractor`.  Then the Comparator for the extracted `key` which must also implement `Comparable` is returned.

What says that this these subsequent fields must also implement `Comparable`?  Look at the signature.  The return type if the `keyExtractor` is `U` and `U extends Comparable<? super U>`.

Here are some examples with explanations.

```
class Bar {
    int val;
    public int getVal(){
        return val;
    }
}

class FooBar implements Comparable<FooBar> {
    String svalue;
    Bar bar;
    int value;
    
    public FooBar(int v, Bar b, String svalue) {
        this.value = v;
        this.bar = b;
        this.svalue = svalue;
    }
    
    public String getSValue() {
        return svalue;
    }
    
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    
    public Bar getBar() {

        return bar;
    }
    
    public int compareTo(FooBar b) {
        return value < b.value ? -1 : value > b.value ? 1 : 0;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "%s, %s, %s".formatted(value, bar, svalue);
    }
}

List<FooBar> list = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(new FooBar(1, new Bar(), "11"),
                new FooBar(2, new Bar(), "AA"),
                new FooBar(3, new Bar(), "BA"),
                new FooBar(4, new Bar(), "CC"),
                new FooBar(5, new Bar(), "2A"),
                new FooBar(6, new Bar(), "AA11"),
                new FooBar(7, new Bar(), "11AA"),
                new FooBar(8, new Bar(), "AAG")));
```

Natural ordering sort of `FooBar`

```
list.sort(null);  //null says use natural ordering.
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
1, stackOverflow.Bar@681a9515, 11
2, stackOverflow.Bar@3af49f1c, AA
3, stackOverflow.Bar@19469ea2, BA
4, stackOverflow.Bar@13221655, CC
5, stackOverflow.Bar@2f2c9b19, 2A
6, stackOverflow.Bar@31befd9f, AA11
7, stackOverflow.Bar@1c20c684, 11AA
8, stackOverflow.Bar@1fb3ebeb, AAG
```

Sort on String `svalue`

```
Comparator<FooBar> comp = Comparator.comparing(FooBar::getSValue);
list.sort(comp);  // sort on svalue
```

prints

```
1, stackOverflow.Bar@33c7353a, 11
7, stackOverflow.Bar@681a9515, 11AA
5, stackOverflow.Bar@3af49f1c, 2A
2, stackOverflow.Bar@19469ea2, AA
6, stackOverflow.Bar@13221655, AA11
8, stackOverflow.Bar@2f2c9b19, AAG
3, stackOverflow.Bar@31befd9f, BA
4, stackOverflow.Bar@1c20c684, CC
```

Sort on object Bar

```
Comparator<FooBar> comp = Comparator.comparing(FooBar::getBar); // oops!
```

This won't work. Can't even define a comparator here because `Bar` does not implement `Comparable` as required  by the signature.  Why was `svalue` allowed?  Because it is a `String` and the String class implements `Comparable`

But all is not lost. The following could be done using `Integer.compare` since `Bar's` value is an int.

```
Comparator<FooBar> comp1 = (f1,f2)-> {
          Bar b1 = f1.getBar();
          Bar b2 = f2.getBar();
          return Integer.compare(b1.getVal(),b2.getVal());
};

list.sort(comp1);
```